# Background opacity effecting child text

Tags: html, css

This could be a duplicate post but I can't seem to find the solution to my html/css layout, apology's in advance:

HTML CODE:

```
<section class="palm-section text-center" id="palm-section">
    <div class="palm-img">
        <h1>Palm Hotel</h1>
        <div class="break-line"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS CODE:

```
 .palm-img h1{ /* Child text to background */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 62px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  z-index: 1;
}


.palm-img{ /* Background */
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(/images/the-palm-962785_1280.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Text is being effected by the parent background's opacity

UPDATE:

Before and after CSS doesnt work, and burying the background inside another div doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.palm-img h1{ /* Child text to background */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 62px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  z-index: 1;
}


.palm-img{ /* Background */
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.palm-img::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/500/500) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="palm-section text-center" id="palm-section">
    <div class="palm-img">
        <h1>Non transparent text</h1>
        <div class="break-line"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

You may use strached pseudo element as background

Answer (score 1):

You could add a transparent color to the `background` like this

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjorth/9q6h10op/2/)**

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) ), 
url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=cold- 
vehicles-water-531880.jpg&fm=jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

`Background` accepts more parameters, so first you add transparent white color through `rgba` like this `linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) )`. Then you add the url.

```css
 .palm-img h1{ /* Child text to background */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 62px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
}


.palm-img{ /* Background */
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) ), url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=cold-vehicles-water-531880.jpg&fm=jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="palm-section text-center" id="palm-section">
    <div class="palm-img">
        <h1>Palm Hotel</h1>
        <div class="break-line"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```